# Nuget errors on build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm getting errors like:

```
Error   20  The command ""\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "\ "" exited with code 1.
```

And

```
Error   19  Unknown option: '-NonInteractive'   Dto
```

Anyone have any idea why I would be getting this?

Comment: What is the version number spit out by the nuget.exe?

Comment: I'm using the beta so I can use the include pre-release stuff

Comment: The nuget.targets file calls this command, but the associated nuget.exe does not support the noninteractive option. This is strange, but it could be the nuget.targets was updated without updating the nuget.exe file in the folder. So what is the version of the nuget.exe file in the \.nuget\ folder? (you can update it by running nuget.exe update -self)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give a legitimate source name or URL to the -source option, such as -source "nuget.org". Otherwise using "" after the -source switch confused the nuget.exe command.